# my room be cleaned vs my room cleaned

Tags: grammar

As I know ‘my room be cleaned ‘ is passive 
The meaning is ‘my room cleaned by someone else.’

So I confused the sentence->
Would you like to have your room cleaned now?

Why isn’t this sentence be ->
Would you like to have your room ‘be’ cleaned now?

Comment: The correct passive sentence is 'Would you like your room _to be cleaned_ now?'

Answer (score 1):

You can also say:

- Would you like your room cleaned? where "to be" is implied.
- I want my room to be cleaned now. [outcome]
- I want to have my room cleaned. [implied: by the housekeepers]